# html canvas set point on path line

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

i have a Canvas Path Script and I am looking for a script, which gives me a point on the line in percent, at 50% the half of the line at 75% 3/4 on the line and so on, see picture

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and sorry for my English (German),

I have copied the script from "https://experiments.hertzen.com/pathfinding/examples/map.html" and deleted the function "$ (canvas) .click (function (e) {...})" , So the one click on the map is not possible.

In the file "jspathfinding.js", under:

"h_score [start] = heurestic_cost_estimate (from, to);
 F_score [start] = h_score [start]; "

this is inserted: "cost_step = Math.round (h_score [start]); "

Thus the steps from beginning to end are counted (total).

My boat would now take an hour from A to B, for example, 345 steps on the map, where the ship is 45 minutes, 75% about 258 steps.
Now he should put a point on the canvas line, where the ship is after 45 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information. Can you edit it so we can see your code for your "Canvas Path Script". Also are you wanting to select a point on the line manually and then get the percent back, or to give the page the percentage and have it tell you where on the line that would be?